# Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, .net, google-analytics, analytics

I have a problem where I can get tracking to work fine, however I cannot seem to get events to work.

We have a DNN website that contains our Online Member Services, the user has the option to be a new member which starts the membership application process. This has been written so that it swaps in the required controls for each step, so the URL doesn't change for the 7 different controls used. This causes us the issue that we can't track the pages.

So with that general background, I thought we could use even tracking instead. No perhaps I haven't correctly set this up, so here is the following code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-28551246-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
</script>
```

which is the standard account info and setup script. I'm trying to track given the folling example on the googles pages

```
<button onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'button3', 'clicked'])"></button>
```

Any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a similar problem. You could append to the URL using something like:

```
window.location.hash = '#/' + pageNumber;
```

and then use this in GA:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', location.pathname + location.search + location.hash]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave that a go, but each page is loaded when the whole application starts so doing that says that every page was visited when landing on the first page. I tried using a button on the 2nd page of the process to call the above code in a function, and while it doesn't fail, and calls the function from start to finish, the analytics script doesnt' appear to get run.

Comment: For some reason, data doesn't get reported instantly. My rule of thumb with GA is always to wait 24 hrs. It worked for me [here](http://www.retaininternational.com/site/solutions/).

Answer (score 0):

I agree that [trackPageView](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration) is a better way to go, so you can see them in the pages report. I assume though that you are not reloading the page, and that is why you still need the click event. If so, you can do something like this

```
function whenUserChangesControls (controlIdentifier) {    
   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/control"+controlIdentifier ]);    
}
```

or whatever you want as the name of page. Make sure it is unique though, otherwise GA will add it to the aggregation of the page if the name you provided matches an existing page name.
Then, you just use `onclick="whenUserChangesControls(cI)"` as a user navigates your page.

Remember that in your pageViews report in GA you will now see each one of them as an independent page view.

Regarding the trackEvent code, it looks good, the error must be somewehere else.